Reality Check - How possible is it for a single human to reach "Space Engineers" level of technological prowess?
How possible would it be for a single mortal human to gain at least the basic staples of modern technology entirely from scratch self-sufficiently, sorta like the protagonist from Space Engineers assuming they didn't rely on some automatic machine like the "assembler" and literally built it themselves?
For restrictions, I'm asking solely about what would be possible for a single mortal human, perhaps a life-long studious systems-engineer, and what would solely be realistically feasible for them if they at the least had all the raw minerals at their feet, and a single average lifespan to manipulate them. They are limited solely by the maximum potential labor of the character's starting body, multiplied by their total potential lifespan, plus any exponential increases in capacity due to the various instruments they create like mills allowing them to easily manufacture precise metal parts, body-modifications allowing them to live sleeplessly and double their potential labor, up to even robots entirely multiplying their capacity for intelligent labor
I have done my research on this, at least as a hobby over the last year. I could speak volumes on the various work-flows and strategies and, even the specific tech-stacks I've arrived to that consolidate as much capacity into as little labor and time and travel, such as skipping fossil-fuels entirely and substituting rubber tires with bladed and gritted metal tires or tracks, or automation and investing heavily into automated power-grids so my character can focus on new technologies but, I feel the scope of this would likely be inconvenient for you guys. What I'm looking for here specifically is largely the "unknown-unknowns" I couldn't possibly see that a degree-holding engineer or automotive technician or computer scientist could effortlessly spot for me.
For example, is it at least feasible for an extremely educated and self-sufficient human to make these basic technologies from scratch:

Energy Production and Storage: basic power-plants from electric, hydrogen or fission; basic gravity-batteries or a methanator to store energy from Hydrogen long-term?

Manufacturing: simple manual or even CNC mills and molds, or even perhaps a simple bootleg lithographer or optic-tweezer array

Expansion of Kinesthetic Ability: simple cars and planes, or even perhaps rockets stripped of all the nonessential and incredibly complex computing, perhaps even simple model-Ts scaled from go-karts to semi-trucks and simple ionic aircrafts just large enough to carry the smallest possible fission plants to fly across the globe many times over

Expansion of Sensory: an electron-microscope; an X-ray; etc

Expansion of calculation and logic: simple computers with vacuum-tubes or some type of simple MOSFET circuitry.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Tools and humans need maintenance. Quite obviously, the character's progress will plateau when the maintenance effort required for themself and for the tools they have built reaches 24 man-hours per day. At that point they will have zero time to invest in building new tools. And that point will be reached at a very low technological level. There is a reason why humanity spent such a long time in the Stone Age.

This! Build a jig for a task. Works for a while. Then you have to fix it. New jig takes time. Extend that to the measuring devices used to make the jig. And so on. Eventually you hire an assistant. You never get enough robotics to help you with the burden unless you start with robotics.

+1 "maintenance of himself" deserves more emphasis. 24 man-hours in a day already sets a hard limit, but he has to sleep, and there go 6-8 hours. He has to eat, which means some mix of farming/hunting/scavenging, all of which takes time and energy. He has to rest. You don't have 24 hours to develop and maintain your technology. You don't even have half that. Robinson Crusoe is a very optimistic best-case scenario, and even he had a massive headstart.

But for most tools, such as knives or saws, maintenance of the tool is proportional to how much you use the tool, and you'll generally get several times more time-of-use out of any given hand tool than time-of-repair. So you can't reach 24 hours of maintenance that way. The tools don't degrade significantly when you aren't using them. This is different for machines like windmills that are always in motion, but you probably don't need more than one windmill for your heavy labor; you are building things for yourself only, so you are working at a scale that a single windmill could power.

@causative: "You can't reach 24 hours of maintenance:" Clothes need to be washed; they wear out and need mending and eventually will need to be replaced. Fenceposts rot and need replacing. The roof needs fixing. Ceramic pots break. Your axes and knives need to be sharpened. The floors need to be sweeped. The broom wears down and needs replacing. The bellows need patching and eventually will have to be replaced. (And a windmill is lousy for powering a lathe. You want a water wheel. And tranmission belts, which have a finite lifespan. And gears. And cutting tools.)

+1 for this answer, there are similar questions like new planet colonists surviving without tools or people being warped into a new world where I've said that humans with knowledge would be able to get to medieval or even early modern stage fairly quickly. But it's impossible for one person by themselves to get far. The more people you have the more they can focus on individual tasks to speed things, 2 people working on a project can more than halve the time it takes to finish as can waste less time switching between tasks.

@AlexP "The floors need to be sweeped" citation needed. Design your house to be low maintenance. The roof won't need fixing for decades. Why do you have any fenceposts? You aren't a farmer, you're a hunter gatherer. Why were you so clumsy to break your ceramic pot? You're supposed to be an expert here. Why do you need transmission belts when you can use gears, with a much longer lifespan? The lathe only wears out in proportion to how much you use it , just like your axes and knives. Use a hand tool for five hours, maintain it for one hour; OK no matter how many tools like that you accumulate.

@causative how long do you think hunter gathering takes? It's notoriously calorie intensive, farming has historically been a big driver of technological advances because you get more calories for less work. Even if you go for hunting it still takes time to hunt, butcher, cure and cook your food. There is only so much time in the day that you have to do all these tasks just for survival before you can dedicate time to advancement.

@HSharp Hunter gatherers take around 15-20 hours a week on acquiring food. That's going to vary with what food sources are around, but we can assume there is plenty. Farmers work more and get a poorer diet besides. The advantage of farming was only that it supports higher population density, not a problem here.

@HSharp Anyway you probably couldn't be a farmer if you wanted to, because you don't have any domesticated crops. You don't have corn or wheat, you just have grass. Maybe you get lucky with a naturally high-calorie plant. But why bother when you can just go make a pit and trap an alien wildebeest.

@causative No, this person has to be a "generalist", not expert in many fields. The person has to be a generalist to gather enough food, enough fuel for cooking, enough materials for shelter, enough raw materials to make tools, enough varied materials so as to maintain said tools, and have the knowledge of what is food, fuel, raw materials, and what constitutes a tool needing maintenance. He has to be a human being.

Reality check: think "early iron age".
Starting from scratch is brutal because, especially at the bottom of the tech stack, scaling up is hard. Even if your character has buckets of every raw resource lying around, just the adventure of making tools will take endless, exhausting amounts of time, and that time will be repeated over and over as those tools dull and break. You need metal tools to efficiently make metal tools.
Watch a video like this: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/-_AKHyhVJks and imagine the effort it takes to hew a single log into a usable beam. For a single person, that would take most of a day... and it still presumes you have

a level
a straightedge
a steel axe
a steel adze

Your character would be trying to do this with, presumably, stone tools, until such time as they could get to making metal ones, an endeavor which is in itself a lot more complicated. And then they'd need to sharpen those tools regularly, which is a whole other level of frustration and labor.
Giving them the raw materials is very generous. I think if they really work at it, they might be able to build a small river-powered saw mill in 5-10 years, though making the actual saw by hammering iron into thin, uniform sheets, and then forming the teeth would be a hell of an adventure.
I can't overstate how long everything will take. He has to make everything. Every tool, every handle, every storage container, every nail. When he's smelting ore, he has to chop all his own fuel, which will deplete his coal or wood reserves.
To forge, he needs a forge, an anvil, tongs, and skills, skills that take years to master. Grinding and sharpening without the proper tools is exhausting and wildly labor intensive. Maybe he can rough-cast an anvil out of some soft metal and a massive mold, but he has no way to harden it. Every tool he makes will be inferior to ours, wear out ten times faster, and take ten times longer to sharpen (generously).
If you supply him with endless food and water that he does not have to find, carry, clean, cook, purify, etc, he may be able to start making crude steel tools by the end of his life. And that would be a brilliant, incredible accomplishment

I get a feeling of well-meaning honesty from your comment, as well as the necessarily very in-depth look at the task-to-task logistics this grand scheme would entail, and I highly highly appreciate it. I'm certainly not gonna get mad if someone simply tells me it isn't possible, not at all, it seems so... 'illusionarily' easy though, very likely similar to how reaching just a picometer beyond the total length of my bones seems like 'JUST' a picometer. Anyway, I highly appreciate your advice, and I get a feeling you won't completely shit on me if I engage with you, so I wanted to say thank you

@Brownpill It's a testament to human ingenuity that it seems so close! We really are standing on the shoulders of giants. Honestly, I would recommend that if this is something you're interested/excited about, do a chunk of research, and then find one specific rung on the tech tree, and implement it. A fun one is pottery. Locate clay in your city, get it to the right consistency, make a coil pot, make a firing pit, gather enough fuel to burn it for a few hours, and see if you can make fired clay. Bonus points if you do not end up using a shovel, axe, or matches.

@Brownpill I did this on a lark when I was in my teens during summer break, and it only took a few weeks of on-and-off work. I genuinely found it a deeply meaningful experience, and I hope you might find it both moving and good research for your story/writing. Mega bonus points if the pot, at the end, is water tight enough to carry a gallon of water ~100 steps or so. That was my goal, and I didn't quite nail it. I hope to repeat the experiment some time in the next decade, if I can find the time.

Ha, that's brilliant, and yes I plan to try similar very soon. Yeah the story is about a human contending against cruel and hedonistic Greek-esque gods, his powers not control of the sea or sky, but of simple disciplined intelligence, honest work-ethic, and humble moral principles.  Entitled whiny nepo-baby gods vs a humble boring engineer like Grady Hillhouse, who is subtley more perfected. It's an extremely meaningful story to me having grown up in a very cruel life surrounded by Greek and Christian religious culture, and I full-on base a lot of my worldview and ideals on it

@Brownpill Part of the reason it seems so easy is that no human in history would actually attempt it this way. Successful innovators don't do it alone. They use the expertise and labor of others to help them on the way. In a market economy that might mean hiring people or buying their products. Otherwise it might be persuading the king to patronize you or the village to support your latest endeavor. It might be that you spend five days making axes to trade so you can spend the sixth honing your craft bit by bit. Humans are a social species, and trying to go it alone wastes that strength.

@Cadence Yeah you're definitely right, I agree

The "Primitive Technology" youtube channel made a furnace out of mud and sticks that was capable of smelting iron. So definitely the engineer can get at least to iron age, not bronze age.

@causative John plant gets talked about above. I really don’t feel like the level of iron work he made it to qualifies as Iron Age.

@DanielB What's left to qualify it as Iron Age? He just needs to make it bigger so it's hotter and can process more ore at a time. If we're assuming that the engineer has knowledge of how to do it and doesn't have to do trial and error, that wouldn't be a problem. "Iron Age" doesn't have much higher prerequisites than "Bronze Age" -  just a hotter furnace plus knowledge, and the engineer already has knowledge.

@causative fair enough. There isn’t really a meaningful difference, I’ll change the title.

Why do you say 5-10 years for a saw? Assuming he knows exactly what to do, he just needs a blob of iron glowing hot (maybe a few weeks or months to make his furnace if he already knows what to do and has all the raw materials) and a hammer, so he hammers it flat and roughly shapes the teeth while it's hot (one afternoon). Then he might be able to use the edge of a thin river rock to sharpen the teeth in a day or two. I sharpen the teeth of my chainsaw a lot with a hand tool, it takes 10 minutes to sharpen the whole saw by removing a visible amount of material.

@causative I’m including the time to build the sawmill, but also, we’re talking a six foot long, heat treated, hardened piece of steel. Given the quality of the iron we see in PT’s videos, I’m not optimistic.

@causative, big sheets of steel are hard: crucible steel, the only sort you can make without already having a steel industry, is not the homogenous material you're familiar with.  If you try hammering out a block of it into a flat sheet suitable for a sawmill blade, it's probably going to break; it's certainly going to break once you start using it.  (If you try to use wrought iron instead, you're going to discover that wood is an incredibly abrasive substance, and you'll be sharpening your saw at least once a day.)

This isn't an entirely theoretical question - there are people who have tried this sort of thing, so you can get an idea of what might or might not be feasible.
The first thing that came to mind is How I built a toaster -- from scratch, a TED talk from 2010. The speaker decided to build a toaster from raw materials. Here it is with and without its case:


He's using the same materials as the original cheap toaster he's copying, so steel and plastic. But he has access to Wikipedia, experts to help him out, a steel mine, and tools such as a leaf blower and a microwave oven. On the other hand it only took nine months, and a single person could probably do better in the same circumstances with more time.
Another reference point is the YouTube channel Primitive Technology. He works much more rigorously, using only tools he makes himself from what's available in his environment. He's managed some impressive feats, such as a brick house and probably a hundred grams or so of iron that required multiple days of labour to produce, not counting the time taken to develop the technique. (Not having access to a leaf blower or a microwave makes a huge difference!)
He also has access to the internet of course, including a community of like-minded people trying to figure the same stuff out. And, just as importantly, he presumably has a well paying job allowing him to eat while also putting time into his hobby. Were it not for that, he would surely be spending his time growing or gathering food rather than perfecting smelting techniques.
From these examples, I would conclude that if they don't have to worry about food and if they have access to a suitable knowledge base, then a single person could probably reach a roughly iron age technology level.
But I don't believe there's any way a single person could reach the point where they can increase their productivity through automation. A single person could probably make wires and a battery given years of effort, but they could never make a vacuum tube, let alone a microchip. A woodturning lathe seems feasible but a dimensionally accurate metalworking lathe is hard to imagine. A steel knife is within the realm of possibility, but an engine block is not. (I don't think a single person could make an engine block by themself even today.) Some things just require economies of scale that a single human can't achieve alone, and they appear quite early on the tech tree (as it were), long before any meaningful form of automation.
From your list:

basic power-plants from electric, hydrogen or fission: I think producing electricity at scale will be difficult, because I don't see a way to do it without coils, and I don't see a way to produce a sizeable coil of wire without substantial machinery. Dealing with fissile material is a poor choice due to the risks and the protective equipment needed, even if it happens to be abundant. If you're the only person on the planet it would be better to burn wood or use a water wheel, or just use your own muscle power.

basic gravity-batteries - if a gravity battery means pumping water uphill and then using the energy later on then sure - this can be done with wooden equipment, assuming the energy will be used mechanically rather than converted into electricity. It would be difficult to make it reliable and efficient enough to be useful though, and it wouldn't be necessary if there is an existing source of flowing water nearby.

a methanator to store energy from Hydrogen long-term - anything involving hydrogen is out of the question. It's hard enough to store it in the modern day and there's no way a single person can develop the materials needed to work with it.

simple manual or even CNC mills and molds - this covers a lot of ground. Mills of one kind or another should be doable, but dimensional accuracy is hard, and computer control out of the question.

a simple bootleg lithographer or optic-tweezer array - I'm not sure what a "bootleg lithographer" is, but if it refers to printing then it's probably possible, although of very little use if there's no-one else to read the printed material. If it refers to microchips then no way - you're not even going to build a clean room by yourself. Optic tweezers are beyond anything remotely imaginable.

simple cars and planes, or even perhaps rockets - no. These all require large-scale production of metal - it can't be done by one person.

an electron-microscope; an X-ray; etc - an electron microscope is utterly impossible. The X-ray is kind of a fun one because although it's a stretch, I can just about imagine someone producing a primitive X-ray machine if they devoted their whole life to that and nothing else. It's not easy. You need not only electricity but a way to step up the voltage (also hard to do without coils), plus substantial skill with glassmaking and glass blowing and some way to pull a vacuum. Once you have a working Crookes tube you also need some chemistry to make photographic plates, although that's probably the easy bit in comparison. Putting an object between the emitter and the plate will form an image. This is dangerous and would serve little purpose, but it's fun to think it might be possible.

simple computers with vacuum-tubes or some type of simple MOSFET circuitry. - you could probably make a simple (slow, unreliable) computer out of relays, but this would take many years of hammering out wire to make the coils. A mechanical computer would be much easier, but in terms of time it would be more efficient to build an abacus and do the calculations by hand instead.



Engine blocks are fitted by hand even today, although that descends into a bit of hair-splitting about what it means to make one "by yourself". (Does a millimeter-accurate lathe count? What about a box of spring steels in different thicknesses? Both of those could be considered "not making the engine" but they're also the product of the work of many people.)

@Cadence I don't actually know much about how engine blocks are made, but in OP's scenario you'd at least have to refine the metal, alloy it, cast it and machine it, plus also lug the engine block and all the fuel, ore etc. around wherever it needs to go. Plus you'd have to make all the machines and so on yourself as well, indeed.

Good. You can't even make a pencil by yourself!

Until 2017 or so, China was unable to produce ballpoint pens from entirely domestic components: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-38566114 Even seemingly simple manufactured goods rely on vast interconnected supply chains.

One thing that is missing from this plan is the artistic skill of technicians.  All of our great engineering marvels stand on the backs of skilled technicians who made is possible.
In particular, things like robotics are very dependent on precision.  Precise manufacturing is an art, not a science.  As a general rule, our precision tools are constructed with higher precision and are used to construct lower precision items.  A robot created before there are gauge blocks to calibrate against is going to have very low precision parts and break down often.  The time cost of break-downs is huge.  And you can't just automate that skill.  I am aware of how to make a gauge block, but I could not make a good one.
Also, mining and refining will be very tricky.  These are activities which really reward an economy of scale.  Refining small quantities is much less efficient than refining large ones.  Even with dynamite, you still have to physically move the ore, and that's a non-trivial amount of energy.  Remember you do not get modern industrial grade robots to help you mine your first iron.
You don't specify what "Space Engineers" level tech is.  The game crosses dozens of levels of technology.  However, you certainly will not reach the space age.  Space is subject to the tyranny of the rocket equation.  Unless you're planning on sending up 1g satellites, you will find you need a tremendous amount of fuel.  This means a large rocket.  You can't make it small.  And large rockets are typically built by hundreds of people over the course of years.  This is with current technology (i.e. tools like 3d printing and CNC machines and thousands upon thousands of hours of computer simulations).

There is no universe in which you create robots before gauge blocks.

I highly appreciate this post and I largely agree. I am skeptical the space-age can be reached and though I am not so certain yet, I feel I vastly lack the applied thought to speak on this here yet so I'll simply say you're probably right. I am familiar with the near-mandatory nature of gauge-blocks, jigs, and machine-precision, but I can't help but think if it even took 40 years to build a simple tungsten-carbide mill and hydro-electric plant and refractory most basic staples of the modern world may be manageable, perhaps I'll update this if I'm wrong to add to the forum!

@Brownpill Are you familiar with the Ginery Complete Metal Working Shop From Scrap series?  It would be a useful point of reference.  He assumes the existence of some things like quality steel and a proper scraper made of tool steel, and constructs things like a lathe, mill, and so forth.  It'd be a useful chapter in the life of your engineer.  Personally, I started on the lathe, but never finished it.  Hand scraping was more of an art than I was willing to learn.  And I got to start with a "flat"

@CortAmmon sorry, extremely busy schedule in trucking, didn't get back to Stack Exchange until now. ...Woooooow, oh my god, those books look absolutely incredible, and yes they seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much! I've actually been working on workflows and plans to produce my own shop from scratch and I've even 3D-modeled an entire semi-truck design based around maximal simplicity, so this's right up my alley I can't thank you enough.

Frame Challenge
Knowledge base is going to be a huge hurdle for this person, I can get from dirt and trees to bowls, cups, knives, axes, and brickwork. Not just theoretically, I have done all the steps, blessing modern [electrical] forced air as well as powered and/or steel cutting tools at every step of the way. That has taken decades of reading and experimentation to go from "I'd like to do that for myself" to practical application. At that I'm still not really working "from scratch", really starting from zero would be orders of magnitude more complex and physically and mentally more demanding. The amount of trial and error would probably get you killed pretty early in the piece, just getting reliable caloric staples in place without starving, or poisoning yourself, would be a feat without a huge knowledge base in areas that most "highly intelligent" people don't delve into. Modern people who get a higher education focus on areas other than, hunting and foraging, personal subsistence farming, hand making pottery, low technology metal extraction etc..., i.e. the baby steps needed long before you have enough of a margin of survival to start building machines that take some of the personal labour out of the daily grind.

If you start with nothing, it will be impossible. At best you might achieve some basic iron working and primitive tools. The time and effort to make a simple gear or spring by hand is enormous. Do hobbyist today make gears and springs? Yes all the time, buy they do so with an extensive set of existing tools and materials.
Simply creating wire for electrical components, You need to smelt the copper, draw it out in wire through a series of steel dies which you will have to make, then develop some kind of flexible insulation.
The equipment to make a transistor, is mind boggling. While people have made very primitives IC chips in their garage, they did using a lot of equipment from actual chip fabs.
Even with a large group of skilled craftsmen, it would be difficult to crate an industrial age tech, let alone a modern one.
Also don't forget while doing this, someone need to grow food and provide shelter. In the USA in 1900, half the population were farmers, need to feed themselves and the other half of the population.

There was a entire genre- back in the 1800 -early 1900 about recreating civilization from scratch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_Crusoe
The problem is- the amount of work and the specialization needed to create certain artifacts. You need several lifetimes of time to re-create certain technologies. And some require several boot-technologies to re-create them- and those need the technology to run efficient. Its a sort of chicken egge scenario. You need pumps to have a working good deep mine, but you need refined iron and coal to create a steam pump, which you can - only get from a mine.
Some of those circustences are also highly location dependent. You need easily accessible coal, water, chemicals, metals all within reach of lousy tools at the start.
A society also needs a financial motor to keep those endavors going- the whole of western capitalism started, when the english trading fleet, going between overseas and motherland, brought in the shipworm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipworm, which made it necessary to armour the ships with copper. Nobody ever pays attention to the financial infra-structure, but you need people organizing that money "side-tracked" into scientific-reinvestments to keep that boot-loop going.
Can one person become a state? Well, yes- if he is immortal, his building technology is impervious to time and he can dissasemble his tasks into time seperated lifetimes with not much time spend on subsistence farming. Cause that eating, eats all your time of day and still depends on specialization for tools and utilities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsistence_agriculture
Under those circumstances, a immortal could drag a cart over a continent. But it would not be fun. And i guess, if all you do is manual labor all day, every day, part of your brain would wither away from lack of usage.Its like being in a labour camp for several lifetimes - until you get to space or forget how to get to space, why you wanted to get to space or you regretfully forget some crucial detail for chip making, preventing you from getting to space. Then you have to reproduce a step with research. Dance the Renaissance, you can do it!

The big hurdle would be knowledge; if you assume they have enough knowledge, it might be possible.
Obviously one person cannot invent their way to the space age in one lifetime. There isn't enough time to test out all the different designs for each technology to get the ones that work well. A thousand lifetimes wouldn't be enough.
But let's say that the path is all laid out for them. They know how to make a smelter out of mud and sticks, they know how to cast iron, they know how to recognize which rocks contain which elements, they know exactly how to put together a vacuum tube, they have encyclopedic knowledge of chemistry, they can write an operating system as fast as they can type, and so on. They landed on planet X with, effectively, a comprehensive guidebook, "How to build a spaceship on planet X from scratch," written by a thousand experts across all necessary subjects. Or something nearly as good. There won't be any missteps.
And also, as you said in the question, all the raw materials are right there at their feet. No need for digging an underground mine, no desperate trekking around the planet. You want aluminum? Well, there's a big pile of bauxite over there by the tree. You need gold? Whole bunch of nuggets over by the other tree. No, not that one, the second one from the right. Yeah, right there.
As for food - we can assume it's available. Berries on the bushes, herds of easily-trapped herbivores with no natural predators, whatever. Hunter gatherers on Earth actually did have a lot of leisure time. Most of the person's time can thus be devoted to following the instructions in the guidebook.
In that case, it could perhaps be done. To ridiculously oversimplify it, first you make a blast furnace out of mud and sticks like the Primitive Technology guy, then you put the right rocks and things in the blast furnace so steel comes out, then you shape the steel so it matches the picture on the box. Voilà, a spaceship. So easy a genius could do it, maybe.
There are some major factors working in your favor.

You don't need to mine or transport anything. It's all right there, literally at your feet; that was given in the question. You have no need for a car, plane, or Bagger 288.
You don't need to mass manufacture anything. You're only building for yourself. You are trying to increase your tech level, not produce a lot of goods people would buy. So you only need one of most tools; one knife, one hammer, one saw, one waterwheel, one set of Whitworth flat plates... one CVD machine.

As soon as you have food and shelter, you can start knapping your first set of stone tools from the obsidian (located in the shade of the fourth tree over there.) You're supposed to be an expert who doesn't need trial and error, so we'll give you, uh... two days to make your knife, axe and scraper. Then you can start on your furnace. You stack clay and reeds into the right shape, chop down trees for firewood, burn the firewood under clay to make charcoal, split some of the wood to make boards that you can make a bellows with. Charcoal isn't even really necessary since coal is a raw material and therefore you have it at your feet already. With no hesitation, no backtracking, the perfect design already in mind, how long could making your furnace take? A week?
Now you can start making bronze tools, cast iron, and fired pottery, and you can make an iron saw for woodworking. You're going to want a power source - a windmill or waterwheel, to drive a hammer for metal working, work your bellows, and other laborious tasks. That might take a few months to build from wood.
With cast iron you can also make a tube for glassblowing, and you can start on your chemistry lab. With the right chemicals, mixed by your expert hands with the assistance of the guidebook, you'll be able to make steel and other alloys. (You don't have standard measurements for your chemistry, but you can make an arbitrary measuring cup and measure in multiples of that.) You can make copper wires. You can't work with any precision yet, but you're already up to 1750s-ish level of technology and I don't think you've been on the planet for even a year.
Making a set of standard measures and an accurate clock should be your next steps. This was very hard for humans in real life because they had to figure everything out, but your guidebook tells you the exact steps. It's not hard for you.
Really, it does seem possible that you might be making computers within your lifetime, and that seems conservative. Maybe in ten years. What stops you from making a vacuum tube right now? You can blow a glass bulb, you have wires of specified alloys, you can use your chemistry lab and the guidebook (and your ample raw materials) to make the right kinds of plastic for airtight seals. But there's no real point in a vacuum tube yet. There's a lot of lab equipment to build first.
Of course, you did start with every possible advantage.

There's a question of how much maintenance would be required on your tools. Notes about that:

Most tools, like hammers and lathes, are used one at a time and only degrade in proportion to how much you use them. If you spend 5 hours using a tool, after which you need 1 hour to maintain it, and if you work for 18 hours a day, you will only ever need 18 * 1/6 = 3 hours a day maintaining your tools no matter how many such tools you accumulate. Maintenance cost does not grow as you make more one-at-a-time tools.
Tools that move by themselves when you aren't using them, such as windmills, water wheels, or centrifuges, will need more maintenance. However, you only need very few of those tools; one water wheel may be sufficient for all your power needs. This is because you are only making things for one person:  yourself. You have a lab, not a factory.
You are not a farmer, you are a hunter-gatherer, so you don't need to maintain a lot of farm equipment and structures. Hunter-gatherers work 15-20 hours a day acquiring food, less than farmers. The only advantage of farming is that it supports higher population density, which is not a concern for you. Humans are apex predators. You probably couldn't be a farmer anyway because you don't have any domesticated plants.


Late Iron Age
The best case study we have on this is probably the Primitive Skills YouTube channel. This guy went out into the woods about 7 years ago precisely to see how far he could get. Here is a summary of his progress:
7 years ago: He lived in a cave, hunted, trapped, fished, and gathered for food.  His only tools were sticks and rocks.
6 years ago: He made a thatchwork hut, he irrigated a field for growing rice and raising fish, and he started making some VERY primitive iron tools (like a small axe and a knife).
5 years ago: He created a water powered hammer for milling, a pottery kiln and some basic ceramics, he diversified his farmland to grow more kinds of plants and vegetables.
4 years ago: He built a proper iron working station including bellows, bloomery kiln, etc. he needed to be able to make a wide range of more complex iron tools like a hammer, a machete, tongs, a hoe, a shovel, chisels, a planer, etc.  He also replaced his thatched hut with a more permanent structure as he began processing his own concrete.
3 years ago: He improved his irrigation system with a weir built of masonry instead of piled dirt.  He made more advanced/specialized tools like a frame saw, a sickle, a garden claw, and a wheelbarrow.  He started making actual furniture like a workbench and a bed.  He started experimenting with primitive clothing and a waterwheel.
2 years ago: He made a much larger and more inclusive set of ceramic kitchenware.  Further expanded his agricultural capacity and fish farm. Finished the water wheel to make a water powered grindstone and saw mill. Domesticated chickens.
1 year ago: Replace thatched roofing with planked roof. Began processing his own cotton into cloth and thread, started making natural dyes to color his cloth, and further diversified his food supply.
This year: Started copper and bronze working. Started making natural rubber, started upgrading some of his buildings to even more permanent masonry and tile roof design. Built a canoe.
Based on his progress we can assume that most of the achievements of the late iron age can be achieved within a single lifetime; however, the further he gets the harder it is to achieve any greater levels because a lot of what sets the industrial revolution's technology apart from medieval tech is economy of scale.  Anything you find on a medieval farmstead is worth it for one person to make as a one off piece of technology.  But when you start looking at more complex machines, motors, electronics, etc. you are moving beyond the scope of one one person can probably do in their lifetime, no matter how smart they are.
